# sailsjs v1.0 PATCH and PUT results in incorrect redirect

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Working on a SailsJs 1.0 blueprint based REST API. Using both PUT and PATCH to attempt record update.

Record updated appears successful, however SailsJs is issuing 302 redirect on receipt of PUT or PATCH which goes nowhere and is subsequently terminated by a 404 error.

```
<- GET /manufacturer/5d28a29de8db6700079bf06f  (8ms 200)
debug: Using `PUT` to update a record is deprecated in Sails 1.0.  Use `PATCH` instead!
<- PUT /manufacturer/5d28a29de8db6700079bf06f  (5ms 302)
<- PUT /manufacturer/Manufacturer/show/5d28a29de8db6700079bf06f  (1ms 404)
<- GET /manufacturer                          (7ms 200)
```

Can anyone shed any light on what is happening here?

sails -v => 1.2.3

Front end is Angular8.1.1, node 12.6.0

Answer (score 0):

`PUT` is depreciated use `PATCH` instead, besides that, its normal for sails to return `302` once you're using `sails-hook-apianalytics` [i also get 302 on some requests]